# Graph between a fork and upstream repository

Tags: git, github, graph, git-log

I would like to see a git log graph, which shows the relationship between one upstream repository and one fork repo.
Something like:
When did the fork forked the upstream?

Just like a clarified git log graph. only have two lines...

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

In Github, you can click on the Forks counter on a repo to see that graph - the fork network for a particular repo. Example: https://github.com/nneonneo/2048-ai/network

Comment: Hi thanks for this info. But what if there are too much forks, github cannot show the graph T T For example: https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/network